# Cordova Download Images and show on Page, where should I save it?

Tags: android, cordova

I've the problem that my app is too big to publish on google play because we have too many media files in it.

Now I'm trying to implement a download when the app is starting the first time.

The download works with Filetransfer plugin from Cordova.

```
function downloadFile(from, to) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(from);

    var folder = cordova.file.dataDirectory + to;
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        folder,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
        },
        function (error) {                
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("download error code" + error.code); 
        },
        false
    );
}
```

As you can see I'm currently saving the files in `cordova.file.dataDirectory + to` where `to` is something like `"www/images/imageName.png"`

Now I'm trying to show the image in one of my pages.
I tried it with different URLs

```
<img src="images/imageName.png" />

<img src="/www/images/imageName.png" />
```

Am I saving it in the correct directory or is there a better option?
Or is there even a simpler way to do some sort of media download to prevent the app from being too big for google play?